# Setting firebase database rules for auto-id node

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, rules

I am trying to set the firebase database rules for my app. Essentially the app has a posts page that allow useres to interact with the diffrent posts.

The problem i have is that when i try to set rules under the "$post_id" branch no data loads in my app, i have a continuous loading screen. but if i remove this "$post_id" branch from the rules then my app loads correctly.

My database looks like this. as you can see the post are loaded under an auto-id node, which is why i tried to add the $post_id to reflect this.

```
{
 "rules": {
 "posts": {
  // the key for each post is stored inside $post_id variable for reference
   "$post_id": {
     // general rules
     ".indexOn": ["timestamp", "likes"],
     ".read": "auth != null",
       // enter the author branch 
       "author": {
         ".read": "auth != null",
         "$user_id": {
           ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
         }
       },
         //enter the comments branch
         "comments": {
           ".indexOn": ["timestamp"]
         }
   }
 }
```

[image: Database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### 1. Make sure you're authenticated.

Check that `firebase.auth().currentUser != null` (for web).
It should allow you to read the `/posts/XXX_some_post_id` paths because you have `".read": "auth != null"` under `rules/posts/$post_id`.

P.S. You don't even need the second `".read": "auth != null"` under `author` because the same rule from `/posts/XXX_some_post_id` applies automatically to all its branches/descendants.

###### 2. Check which path you're reading from.

There is a good chance (I did the same mistake in the past) that you're trying to read from the upper `posts` path rather than from `posts/XXX_some_post_id`.
That will fail because no rules are specified for `posts`. The rules are currently provided only for `posts/$post_id` which is one level deeper. So you need to either

- read directly from `/posts/XXX_some_post_id` every time, or
- add rules right under the posts:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      ".read": "auth != null",

      "$post_id": {
        // other rules here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bulat, i am still a bit confused. Do you mean i should reformat the way i wrote the rules? Could you show me an example of what you mean please.

Comment: {
   "rules": {
     "posts": {
         // general rules
       ".read": "auth != null",
         ".indexOn": "timestamp",
          // the key for each post is stored inside $post_id variable for reference
          "$post_id": {
         //other rules
             }
          }
     }
   }
 }

Comment: Hey there,
Yes, this looks right to me. Did it help?
It also depends on how you access the data. Could you also share the line of code where you read from the database?

Comment: Cool! I’m glad it helped